# Background with logo and text infant of the logo

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds

I'm trying to design a background for my presentation, the background should have the logo and some text similar to the picture. [image]

I used this code, but the text is too wide to fit under the logo

```
   \documentclass[10pt]{exam}
    \usepackage{background}
    \newsavebox\mybox
    \savebox\mybox{\tikz[opacity=0.1]\node{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{logo}
    \underline{\textbf{xxxx}}};
    }
    \backgroundsetup{angle=0,contents={\usebox\mybox}
   \begin{document}
    My document

   \end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I did that and the code is compilable now

Comment: Better, but it does not compile. 1) substitute `logo` (which we don't have) with `example-image-a` (which is in standard distribution). 2: you have a missing brace: `File ended while scanning use of \backgroundsetup .`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I got your question, but: do you mean this?

I had to fix a couple of things (see comments).

I have put all the background image in the Ti*k*Z node (but you can play with that) and made the node align multiple lines centering them)

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{exam}
    \usepackage{background}
    \newsavebox\mybox
    \savebox\mybox{%
        \tikz[opacity=0.1]\node[align=center]{%
            \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}\\[-8pt]
        {\tiny\textbf{xxxx}}};
    }
    \backgroundsetup{angle=0,contents={\usebox\mybox}}
\begin{document}
    My document
\end{document}
```

[image]

But notice that the package gives you a warning in the TeXLive 2020 release:

```
Package everypage Warning: Functionality similar to this package has recently
(everypage)                been implemented in LaTeX. This package is now in
(everypage)                legacy status.
(everypage)                Please, don't use it in new documents and packages.


Package everypage Warning: You appear to be running a version of LaTeX
(everypage)                providing the new functionality.
(everypage)                Doing the best to deliver the original `everypage`
(everypage)                interface on top of it. Strict equivalence is
(everypage)                not possible, breakage may occur.
(everypage)                If truly needed, Use `everypage-1x` to force the
(everypage)                loading of an older code base.
```

Comment: I want the size of the text to be mush smaller and closer to the logo

Comment: That doesn't work, the size of the text remains constant

Comment: Yes, because I typed that wrongly. It's `{\tiny\textbf{xxxx}}`

Comment: it didn't work, unfortunately.